# Binding .click and .blur event handlers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm running into a problem binding both a `.blur` and `.click` event handler to the same clickable element. The UX I'm going for is as follows:

a user clicks on the search icon and the search field appears; when a user clicks again on the search icon, they can collapse and hide the search field. If they click away, the search field should hide.

So far, I'm able to achieve *most* of what I want, except that I can't get the `.click` binding to toggle the class after it's been clicked. I'm thinking it's possibly because after being toggled the `$` selector doesn't have any results to select? I'm relatively new to JavaScript so I'm a little unclear on exactly how JavaScript or jQuery would handle something like this.

**Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TpXJe/1/**

**Edit**: including code here so future Stack Overflow users can see it:

---

html:

```
<form class="hidden-xs search-container navbar-right search-form" method="get">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="search-box" type="search" class="search-box" name="s" class="search-field form-control" />
        <label class="hide">Search for something</label>
        <label for="search-box"><span id="searchDivider">|</span>

            <div class="icon-continer"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-icon"></span>

            </div>
        </label>
       </div>
</form>
```

---

css:

```
.search-container {
  right: 0px;
}

#searchDivider {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top:31px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: @brand-success;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 200;

}
// Style the search box



$tl: .3s; // transition length

.search-box {
  outline-width: 0;
  transition: width $tl, border-radius $tl, background $tl;
  position: absolute;
  right:-37px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  & + label .search-icon {
    color: black    }
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px transparent;
    & + label .search-icon {
       color: white    }
  }
  &.focused {
    transition: width $tl cubic-bezier(.18,.57,.25,.94), border-radius $tl;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding-left: 15px;
    cursor: text;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: auto;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    & + label .search-icon {
      color: black;    }
  }
  &:not(:focus) {
    text-indent:-5000px;    } // for more-graceful falling back (:not browsers likely support indent)
}

#search-submit {
  position: relative;
  left: -5000px;
}

.search-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: -45px;
  top: 14px;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 23px;
}
```

---

js:

```
  $('.search-icon').click(
  function () {
      $('.search-box ').toggleClass(' .search-box focused');
  });
  $('.search-box').blur(
  function () {
      $('.search-box').removeClass('focused');
  });
```

Comment: Can you share your code here so it is preserved for future visitors to SO?

Comment: on click of icon again its actually firing both events blur and click

Comment: i think your click event function needs to look like this `$('.search-box ').toggleClass('focused');`.  The way you have it now is not correct.  I am not sure if that fixes your actual problem though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ehsan said in the comments, it appears that clicking the icon while it has already been clicked once fires both click() and blur() events. I just added in a variable to represent the state of clicked/unclicked and it works for me! Also in the updated fiddle below is what I believe you intended to do that Jacob mentioned in the comments-the class name is 'focused' not '.search-box focused'.

[Updated JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/TpXJe/7/)

Here is the JS Code:

```
var clicked = false;

$('.search-icon').click(

  function () {
      if (clicked) {
      $('.search-box ').removeClass('focused');
          clicked = false;
      } else {
          $('.search-box ').addClass('focused');
          clicked = true;
      }
  });


  $('.search-box').blur(

  function () {
      $('.search-box').removeClass('focused');
```

Comment: This works great, except that the field doesn't get blurred and you can still see text that's entered in; I tried adding a `blur` method on the same selection, but it won't blur. Any idea why?

Comment: @markthethomas It seems if the icon is clicked once (expanding the search bar), and clicked again, the blur() handler is triggered **before** the 2nd occurrence of the click handler. With boolean flags alone I wasn't able to produce the sequence you desired. (A sequence of 2 clicks fires click(), blur(), click(), with the last click being undesired in that specific instance, but the sequence of clicking the icon, clicking outside the bar, and clicking the icon again, also triggers the same click(), blur(), click() sequence. I'm not sure how to make the same events produce different outcomes

Comment: @markthethomas since I am relatively new to jQuery, and not entirely sure if what you desire can be produced exactly because of the issues described in my above comment, here's a link to what you want [done with css:](http://callmenick.com/2013/04/03/expanding-search-bar-using-css-transitions/) I hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

What I have stated to do recently is set up all my event listeners as a variable (object). It makes being able to assign multiple events to a single object very easy.

```
/**
 * Event listeners.
 * Params: element, event : method
 * NOTE: element is passed in as a string, not jQuery object!
 * This so we have the possibility of multiple events for a single element (eg.    focus & change for the same element). 
 * 
 */
 eventHandlers: {
     'a click': 'onAnchorClick',
     'a hover': 'onAnchorHover'
 }, 


/**
 * Registers all event listeners/handlers.
 * @returns {void}
 * 
 */
registerEventHandlers: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.each(this.eventHandlers, function(key, val) {
        var split = key.split(" ");
        var element = split[0];
        var event = split[1];
        $(document).on(event, element, that[val]);
     });
 }

...

/**
 * Event listener for all anchor click events.
 * @param {object} event | The click event.
 * @returns {void}
 * 
 */
onAnchorClick: function(event) {
     console.log('click event');

    // For example purposes:
    var ga_eventData = {
        'category': 'Text Link',
        'action': 'Click',
        'label': event.currentTarget.innerText,
        'optionalData': {
            'page': window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname
            }
        }
        GA.registerEvent(ga_eventData);  // GA is my google analytics module in this example
},
/**
 * Event listener for all anchor hover events.
 * @param {object} event | The hover event.
 * @returns {void}
 * 
 */
onAnchorHover: function(event) {
    console.log('hover event');
}

...
```

Then in my initialization method, I simply call:

```
/**
 * Initialization method.
 * @returns {void}
 * 
 */
initialize: function() {
    var that = this;
    that.registerEventHandlers();
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessary and excessive. You are duplicating functionality that already exists inherently in javascript.

Comment: I do this so I am able to attach any given method(s) to any given event at any given time. For example, Analytics - I can create an analytic data object once (in the click event) then pass that info along to my analytics module. I can also listen for a specific event/click/whatever and respond accordingly.

Comment: You can already attach any given "method" to any given event at any given time. That is the very nature of event listeners. I am not writing this to be mean, I am letting you know that this approach is not good.